# How to ovveride a block in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-block, magento-community

I want to override the Catalog module. So I created my first custom module,

I initiated it in `app/etc/modules/MyCompany_Catalog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then In `app/code/local/MyCompany/Catalog` I created Block,Controllers,etc folder.

In etc/config.xml as I want to override `Configurable.php`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>MyCompany_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

In `Controllers/IndexController.php` :

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Catalog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

}
?>
```

And Finally In `Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php` :

```
<?php
class Shore_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
    protected function _prepareOldPrice($price, $isPercent = false)
    {
        $price = 0;  // Ramya
        if ($isPercent && !empty($price)) {
            //$price = $this->getProduct()->getPrice() * $price / 100;  
        }

        return $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($price, true));
    }
}
?>
```

But I didn't find the change applied. I found it to work when I changed it in `base` as a try. But as it not a good practice to edit I created a custom module. But it is not working here. Kindly correct me If I was wrong in my above steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with config,xml file as below, Replace **`tag with catalog`**,

In your module you need catalog module override so you have to used catalog tag before rewrite tag. you have to define your core module name before rewrite tag. if you want override customer module file that time you need define customer tag.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_Catalog>
    </modules>   
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>MyCompany_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

Comment: Just now I updated that in my question. But not working. Was I correct in overriding the block?

Comment: yes remaining is correct for you just remove cache and check

Comment: hey thank you so much. It worked. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: yea sure. Sorry for delay.